# Prove that if $x+y+z=3$ then $x=y=z=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $xyz=1$ and $x>0,y>0,z>0$ prove that $x+y+z=3\leftrightarrow x=y=z=1 $.

The $\leftarrow$ is obvious, but I'm having a difficulty proving the other way. I understand that I can assume $z\geq y\geq x$ but can't think of how I continue from here.

Comment: Hint: How do you prove something is equal to another.

Comment: AM GM for 3 terms $(a+b+c)/3 \ge \sqrt[3]{abc}. $Equality holds for $x=y=z$.

Comment: Hmm. Please, tell us a bit more about the tools you have at your disposal! AM-GM inequality kinda stands out here. But you can use, instead, Lagrange multipliers. Or even give a calculus proof for the AM-GM in the case of three vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Properties_of_ordered_fields) for properties of ordered fields.

Given $xyz=1,x+y+z=3$, assume that $x=y=z=1$ is false. One needs to provide a contradiction. Without loss of generality, one may assume $z$ is the smallest, so $0<z<1$, or equivalently $z=1-h$, where $0<h<1$. Note that by the properties of ordered fields, one has $$\frac 1 h>1>0,{\rm ~and~}\frac 1{1-h}>1,$$ multiplication by positive number preserves inequality, and a square is nonnegative. Now the conditions $x+y=3-z,xy=1/z$ show that $$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow (3-z)^2-\frac 4z\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow (2+h)^2-\frac 4{1-h}\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow h^2+4h+4-\frac 4{1-h}\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow h^2+4h+4\cdot \frac {-h}{1-h}\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow h+4-\frac 4{1-h}\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow h+4\cdot \frac{-h}{1-h}\geq 0$$$$\Rightarrow 1-\frac 4{1-h}\geq 0,$$ which is not possible since $\frac 4{1-h}>4>1$. This contradiction shows that $x=y=z=1$ must hold instead. QED

Answer (score 1):

Write $z = 3-x-y$ so $$xy(3-x-y)=1$$ or $$yx^2 +(y^2-3y)x+1=0$$ Now when does this **quadratic equation** on $x$ with parameter $y$ have a solution? When $$D= y(y-2)(y-1)^2\geq 0$$

Now beacuse of simmetry we can assume that $y$ is the smallest one so $y\leq 1$.

If $y<1$ we get $D<0$ a contradiction. So $y=1$...

Comment: I can't use roots.

Comment: Why?................

Comment: Ok then write $(x+y+z)^3\geq 27 xyz$

Comment: Can only use the standard field axioms.

Comment: If you want to go from the begining then it will be HARD

Comment: This is probably a proof related class, where you may only use things proven to that point... Which kinda makes it hard to help.

Comment: It is, in the previous question I proved that $x+y+z\geq 3$. But I don't think any other thing I proved is useful here.

Comment: I also proved that for $z>1, 0<x<1, xz\in \mathbb Q$ $1+xz<x+z$. Can't see how I can use it here.

Comment: The standard field axioms doesn't include inequalities. So how can you prove an inequality using only those?

Comment: Do you know how to solve quadratic equation?

Comment: Correction - standard field axioms and simple operations with inequalities. For example, that if $x>y, z>0$ then $xy>xz$. More or less I can use simple algebraic operations, but not powers greater than 2.

Comment: Yes, I can solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: Also obviously can use trichotomy for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the identity
$$x+y+z - 3\,\sqrt[3]{xyz}\;=\;\frac 12\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}+\sqrt[3]{z}\right)
\left[\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{y}\right)^2
+\left(\sqrt[3]{y}-\sqrt[3]{z}\right)^2
+\left(\sqrt[3]{z}-\sqrt[3]{x}\right)^2\right]$$
From the givens the LHS is zero. Which is only possible if on the RHS each of the three squares vanishes. Which yields $x=y=z$.